# Reset supervisor password on Toshiba Portégé

Tags: bios, passwords, uefi, reset

I want some thing "software" that can help me to remove bios password on my **Toshiba Portégé Z30-A-12T. 
I still remember the user password for bios but i can't remove it.

I hope to find a software to remove user and supervisor password;

Thank you :)

Comment: You should contact Toshiba.

Comment: hehe they will say bring it to us :p i want just some help from someone

Comment: From my previous experience working for a Toshiba OEM repair depot you'll need to contact Toshiba.  See the duplicate question I'm about to flag this as...

Answer (score 0):

Cmos reset will probably void your warranty.
Screw the thing open and consult the mobo's manual on the location and settings of the cmos jumper and set it in the 'reset/clear' position. Boot fully at least once and put the jumper back in 'normal' position. Your bios/uefi settings have been cleared.